# Error trying to set concurrency message limit in MassTransit

Tags: masstransit

I have a simple .NET worker service app I'm using to test MassTransit. I'm trying to use the example here: https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/middleware/concurrency-limit.html

Specifically, I'm trying to use the UseConcurrentMessageLimit() method, but the *e.Consumer<SubmitOrderConsumer>* portion is highlighted with an error that says "Reference to type 'IReceiveEndpointConfigurator' claims it is defined in 'MassTransit', but it could not be found".

I'm using the MassTransit 8.0.2.

I'm wondering if there's some additional NuGet package I need to include to get this working. I tried using the Memory Transport, the SQS one, the RabbitMQ one (in case it was transport-specific), I keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, two unrelated answers:

1. The reference to type not found is due to some assembly in your solution referencing an old version of MassTransit, or an obsolete package. Generally, all MassTransit.* packages should have the same version number. If a package is not available in the current version, that package was probably deprecated and no longer used.
2. The `UseConcurrentMessageLimit` filter is no longer recommended and should not be used. Instead, either set the `ConcurrentMessageLimit` property on the receive endpoint, or on the consumer configurator.

Comment: Many thanks, that worked. I'll take the opportunity and thank you for the work on this library. I don't even know how you find the time to answer all these questions!